# HBASE error : Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'

Tags: java, hbase

I have jdk-15.0.1 on my laptop, and have installed HBASE (hbase-2.2.6 version).

I followed every steps to install HBASE on this link : https://www.learntospark.com/2020/08/setup-hbase-in-windows.html

The problem is that when I try running HBASE in my command line using :

```
start-hbase.cmd
```

I get the following error message :

```
Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
ERROR: Could not determine the startup mode.
```

As a beginner, I tried scouring around for information, but nothing that matches my problem.

I would be glad for any help you could give me.

Answer (score 2):

CMS garbage collector is removed in JDK 15, thus `UseConcMarkSweepGC` too is removed.

[JEP 363: Remove the Concurrent Mark Sweep GC](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/363)

So, either you should switch back to java 8 or 11, or you should modify below line:

```
set HBASE_OPTS="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC" "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

with

```
set HBASE_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```